# Symfony Heroku crashed app H10

Tags: symfony, heroku

I upload symfony application witjout error, begin call heroku run bash, check validate db and run doctrine:schema:update --force and check doctrine:schema:validate everything ok, but when open app heve error

check log and see this

```
2016-12-04T16:28:54.236638+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=academy-lern.herokuapp.com request_id=449cbb19-d0d8-49da-aba7-bed4b9483a61 fwd="176.241.128.140" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I enter to heroku run bash and open parameters yml everything ok, paraeters for my addons add

this my log

```
2016-12-04T17:09:11.123385+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-04T17:09:14.402866+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/`
2016-12-04T17:09:16.514245+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-12-04T17:09:16.528905+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-04T17:09:16.448703+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2: No such file or directory
```

I have ProcFile

```
echo "web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/" > Procfile
```

what I'am doing wrong ?

Comment: what did you do to find out what was wrong as i am stuck at the same situation, procfile seems to be fine.

Answer (score 2):

In symfony > 3 dir bid created in vendor in old version in roo app
so for version > 3.0

```
vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/
```

for < 3.0

```
bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/
```